# (vs code) kill terminal button disappeared

Tags: visual-studio-code

I do not how I changed the settings, but kill terminal button disappeared from panel tab in vscode.
Can anyone tell me how to reset the terminal button settings.

[vs code terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdSY0.png)

Comment: For me it stopped appearing as there was less space on right side of the terminal name. After dragging the sidebar to the left, the kill terminal button started appearing again.

Answer (score 2):

solved
remove the following line in setting.json

```
"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true
```